# Apache Proxy like ProxyPass / http://hostname/app-context on virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

can anybody tells me what's wrong on this:

there is an app on tomcat running with context mobile and we want to have it available on root context of url m.example.com, I thought that this will done the job but it's not true, everytime I put request to this url apache adds one /mobile behind so after a few requests to m.example.com the final request could looks like m.example.com/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName m.example.com
    ServerAlias m.example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://localhost/mobile/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/mobile/


    <Proxy http://localhost/mobile/*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>        

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
ProxyPass /mobile !
```